# How to unmask the SIP credentials in the Zoiper VoIP application?

Tags: password, voip

Is it possible to unmask the SIP credentials stored in the Preferences of the Zoiper VoIP application ? I couldn't find any password unmask application for that and I can't find the password in my Keychain.

Comment: Which application?

Comment: Zoiper (VoIp phone)

Comment: So you are basically asking how to recover your password for Zoiper? You might get better results if you rephrase the question accordingly.

Comment: Please edit some details into the question. Your OS type and level, hardware perhaps. We have a guide on [ask] if it's not clear what we're after to make a good question here.

Comment: It's not Zoiper account that I need password for. It's SIP credentials that are put in Zoiper settings. It was registered somewhere else. I need exactly what I asked. Can I unmask the password somehow ? Thank you.

Comment: Then please edit your question and describe your situation in more details. Most probably it will not be possible to prevent the masking, but there may be other ways to recover your lost information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to the folder that Zoiper is installed
- Find the file zoiper.cfg which is essentially an xml file
- Your SIP username and password are located between `<account>` and `</account>`.

Answer (score 2):

From [zoiper.com](http://www.zoiper.com/support.php):

> Use the [password recovery](http://shop.zoiper.com/password_recovery.php) option to reset your password. You will receive your new password by email.
>   Once changed the password becomes applicable for all your certificates. 
>   This password is to be used for activation and reset of your Zoiper certificates. It is not part of your VoIP account credentials.

Comment: It's not Zoiper account that I need password for. It's SIP credentials that are put in Zoiper settings. It was registered somewhere else. I need exactly what I asked. Can I unmask the password somehow ? Thank you.